# na.omit not removing NA (data is numerical)

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have just merged two data frames and am trying to remove rows with a NA in the value column. As of now I have..

```
t.dup.rights <- merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, by = "ID", all = T)
na.omit(tdup.rights$value)
```

The value column has either a 1 or NA. I used

```
is.numeric(t.dup.rights$value)
```

to double check that r doesn't think it's a factor. After I run the na.omit function the data frame appears to remain unchanged. I am working with a particularly large data set (200K obs). I am also using the dplyr package.

Comment: tdup.rights[!is.na(tdup.rights$value),] - you can also use `merge( ..., all = F)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tidyr::drop_na`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/drop_na.html)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(
  x = sample(c(NA, 1, 2), 10, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(c(NA, 1, 2), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df

#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>        x     y
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     NA    NA
#> 2      1     2
#> 3      2     2
#> 4     NA     1
#> 5      2    NA
#> 6      1    NA
#> 7     NA    NA
#> 8      2     2
#> 9      1    NA
#> 10    NA     2

drop_na(df, x)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     2    NA
#> 4     1    NA
#> 5     2     2
#> 6     1    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly